# Is making a logo for a cake shop haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, sin

I got a job to make a logo for a Facebook page which sells cake and food items.They say they make cakes with halal ingredients. They also sell cakes for occasions like birthdays and anniversaries which is not permissible in Islam. Is it permissible to make a logo for this online shop according to Sharia'?

Comment: if logo content only text, it's halal , if logo consist of non islamic content (like doll pic, animal face etc ), it will be haram... it's better clear about what type of content will contain in your client logo and describe more specific.. then you got better answer ... plz describe more ... or  ask specific question....

Comment: Is it haram if he sells birthday, anniversary cakes?

Comment: as far as I know ,  birthday or anniversary celebration is not islamic culture.. also It's different question...

Comment: My question is can i design logo for a shop that sells all types of cake that includes birthday anniversary wedding cake

Comment: please add those word and focus on it ... that is why I wrote in my first comment that _plz describe more ... or ask specific question..._  something like _is making logo haram for cake who made cake for non islamic culture?_

Comment: Can you answer this?

Comment: Are you a Islamic scholar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119570/discussion-between-sadiqur-and-).